# Real Time Version Control Software

Tags: windows, version-control

There's no shortage of traditional version control software, but I'm looking for something that doesn't require me to constantly commit. In other words, I am searching for background software that automatically keeps a history of all files in a directory. If possible, I would also like to be able to add commit notes myself for benchmarks later on.

I have no preference on whether or not the solution is a web service or a local service that I host myself, as long as it is free or has a reasonable one-time fee (no subscriptions please). Performance and Hard Drive Usage are not issues.

I hope that I'm not being too specific with my request. I searched the web for solutions, but I could not find any software that does what I want. For compatibility, I have Windows 7 64-bit and an AMD processor.

Comment: This SO question has some helpful suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688546/continuous-version-control

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should consider [Dropbox](http://db.tt/aJ4mQoz). It's not strictly version control software, but it runs in the background and syncs your files to the cloud.

They give you 2GB of storage for free (more if you pay a subscription), and from their website, you can view the different versions of the files in your Dropbox folder.

Comment: I was going to recommend the same thing.  Please note that if you use @egoard's link, both you and he get an extra free 250MB.  And there's an extra (paid) "packrat" option for keeping versions longer than 30 days.

Comment: Thanks! Dropbox is as good as any person could want. My only thing I would change would be to allow unlimited revisions, but 30 days of real time revisions is good enough for me :)

Comment: [EngineOne](https://engineone.io) was created just for that. (Disclosure - I'm one of the founders).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any software or services that do this.

I did come up with a quick idea though
This idea seems like a bit of a hack and it is right off the top of my head (so issues may come up in implementing).

Create an app/service that uses the [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to detect changes/creation/deletion to the location(s) that you want to version.
When a detection is made, do [bat/cmd/powershell/code/ect] that uses the command line (or other) interface of [insert version control software here] to do a commit.

I think it's fairly straight forward. I *think* it's easy to implement, but that's the danger of 'top of the head' ideas. A direction to look for rolling your if nothing else. :)

Comment: ooh! I could see how that can work. I'd prefer to find a ready made solution, but if none of these solutions work well enough for me, I suppose I can mash together some Python code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any stock solutions, but depending on your IDE/Make system, you should be able to create a postbuild event that commits the files to your "regular" version control system after a successful build (the version control system will need an external API or CLI for this to work).  You can then add commit notes, etc. in the version control system at your leisure.

Comment: I use Sublime Text, and AFAIK, it doesn't support that =/ Also, I would like to use version control for other forms of files as well.